# Chai testing TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I'm a new learner express.js I want to test simple post and get operations with tdd mechanism. I created the test, route, index and db files but when I try to test POST method it gives me this error.

[image]

This is my routes/task.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/api/task", async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const task = await new Task(req.body).save();
        res.send(task);
    } catch (error) {
        res.send(error);
    }
})
```

This is my test/task.js

```
let chai = require("chai");
const chaiHttp = require("chai-http");
const { send } = require("process");
let server = require("../index");

//Assertion Style
chai.should();

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Tasks API', () => {

        
    /** 
     * Test the POST Route
     */
     describe('POST /api/task', () => {
        it("It should POST a new task", () => {
            const task =  {task: "Wake Up"};
            chai.request(server)
                .post("/api/task")
                .send(task)
                .end((err, response) => {
                    response.should.have.status(201);
                    response.body.should.be.a('string');
                    response.body.should.have.property('id');
                    response.body.should.have.property('task');
                    response.body.should.have.property('task').eq("Wake Up");
                    response.body.length.should.be.eq(1);
                done();
                });
        });
    });
});
```

This is my db.js

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()

const DBSOURCE = "db.sqlite"

let db = new sqlite3.Database(DBSOURCE, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      // Cannot open database
      console.error(err.message)
      throw err
    }else{
        console.log('Connected to the SQLite database.')
        db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todo (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            task text
            )`,
        (err) => {
            if (err) {
                // Table already created
                console.log(err);
            }
        });  
    }
});


module.exports = db
```

And this is my index.js

```
const connection = require('./db');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors"); 


const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());



app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World');

});

app.post('/api/task', (req, res) => {

    res.status(201).send(req);

});




app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`)); 

module.exports = app;
```

The thing that I try to do is building a test case to test the post method. I think I couldn't built the correct relations the files.

Comment: What the immediate issue is that you're not using your route. It's hitting the app.post in the index.js. Then you're trying to send back the entire request, I assume you want to just return the task or something. Presumably this was testing code and now you want to add your route to be used by express.

Comment: The routes file requires 1) a module.exports = router 2) a change to the path to just /task. The DB file requires a definition for TASK. The index.js requires an app.use('/api',routes) and a require for the routes. The test checks that the response is a string, then expects it to have properties (is it supposed to be an object or a string?)
and finally the test checks to see if it's an array (or a string again) with length.
read up on routing here - https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, just by doing a POST request to `/api/task`, the error will appear. That is because of these lines in index.js:

```
app.post('/api/task', (req, res) => {
    res.status(201).send(req);
});
```

The `req` parameter is circular, hence cannot be JSON-stringified.

#### Solution

In **`routes/task.js`** export the `router`:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/api/task", async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const task = await new Task(req.body).save();
        res.send(task);
    } catch (error) {
        res.send(error);
    }
})

// By adding this line you can export the router
module.exports = router
```

In **`index.js`**, include the `routes/task.js` file and pass it to `app.use(...)`, also remove the now-obsolete `/api/task` route:

```
const connection = require('./db');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const taskRoutes = require("./routes/task")


const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.use(taskRoutes)

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));

module.exports = app;
```

This way we got rid of the circular structure stringifying and the tests should now pass.